# React TypeError: x.filter is not a function

Tags: reactjs

When I run tis code on localhost did not show any error

```
const displayProduct = product
.filter(prod =>
    prod.category.includes(filters.category) &&
    prod.brand.includes(filters.brand) &&
    prod.type.includes(filters.type)
  )
.filter((product)=>{
    if (searchTerm == ""){
        return product
    }else if(product.productName.replaceAll(/\s/g,'').toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase().replaceAll(/\s/g,''))){
        return product
    }
})
.slice(pagesVisited,pagesVisited + productPerPage)
.map(product => {
    return(
        <div className='imageContainer ' key={product.id}>
            <img src={product.productImageOne?require(`../../Images/${product.productImageOne}`):null} className="image"/>
            <div className='productName'>
            <Link style={{ textDecoration:'none' }} to="/productsDetails" state={{ product:product }}>{product.productName?product.productName:null}</Link>
            </div>
        </div>   
    )
})
```

But when I host my website on a server it show "TypeError: x.filter is not a function"..
How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This occurs because `product` isn't defined yet.
In your local machine, `product` may be an array containing your data when React is processing the view because your server may be on you machine, but on your server, you may need to wait longer in order to make your HTTP request.

You can fix your error by replacing all your `product.` occurence by `product?.`, such as:

```js
const displayProduct = product
  ?.filter(prod =>
    ...
  )
  ?.filter((product)=>{
    ...
  })
  ?.slice(...)
  ?.map(...)
```

Plus, you may need to check product or displayProduct's value before, to add a loader or spinning stuff showing data's fetching.